# Dual Boot Lubuntu Windows 10 Only Windows 10 Loading

Tags: windows-10, lubuntu, dualboot

it's the first time I encounter this issue. I have several other computers on which I have two OS and I had never had to do anything to have a bootloader where I can choose which one I want to start.

Now, I just installed Lubuntu on a laptop which already has Windows 10 and for the first time, it doesn't show up when I start the computer. Only Windows 10 loads. Only one disk (apart from USB) shows up in the BIOS boot settings so I can't choose anything else.

After trying everything I knew, I tried boot-repair, I did the recommended boot-repair thing and yet only Windows 10 loads as if there were no other OS installed on that machine. Here is the
[boot repair report](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vFQNYtrjqK/) .

Any help appreciated, thank you!

### Update

Executed both bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
and bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
Didn't work. To revert back if none worked, the command is:
bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} path

Still looking for a solution.

### Update

For anyone encountering a dual boot issue, Super Grub2 Disk seems like it can do all the work for you. I have no idea what it did. I booted Lubuntu using it. It said there were some updates, I updated, then I thought why not try and reboot normally to see if anything happened, and there we go, Grub bootloader was showing normally and the problem is gone. I can now choose either Windows or Lubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable Fast Startup in Windows 10, shutdown and reboot.

This can be achieved by executing the following `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System]
"HiberbootEnabled"=-
```

More methods are described in the article
[How to Turn On or Off Fast Startup in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I did that already. Otherwise, I wouldn't have been able to boot from the USB to install Lubuntu.

Comment: Did you try the advice at lines 95-100 of the boot repair report? The report also says that you have 2 Ubuntu installations on sda9 and sda10, how come?

Comment: I haven't tried bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi yet as I don't understand the command precisely. I wanted to read and learn more about it first. Regarding the two installations on sda9 and sda10, I don't know, I booted Lubuntu from a USB and I let it partition and install everything itself.

Comment: Hi, I did both bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi and bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi , still Windows 10 only boots. Do you know how to revert the changes for those commands? I saw it somewhere but I checked hundreds of pages and can't find it anymore...

Comment: Have you checked boot parameters in the BIOS?

Comment: Yes, there is only one disk and USB in my boot options, nothing more. I initially wanted to install Arch on this laptop and I had the same issue, only Windows would boot. I thought I had messed up the installation because it's been a while since I installed it on a machine so I thought Lubuntu was going to do everything automatically and solve my problem. When I first installed Arch, I thought I may have messed up with Grub. I formatted everything and restarted with Lubuntu. I'm really confused. I've had computers with dual boots since the early 2000s and I never saw that before.

Comment: If it doesn't boot directly into Grub, try the [Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) to repair it.

Comment: It's working perfectly with Super Grub2 Disk but having to boot from a USB every time doesn't seem like the best option haha

Comment: Can Super Grub2 fix the grub boot?

Comment: That's what I'm investigating right now. Updating Lubuntu right now and then I'll check the whole Grub boot config from Lubuntu. If all this works, I'm definitely going to write a detailed tutorial on the topic. I checked hundreds of pages and nothing worked. Thank you so much for your help and prompt replies so far. I would have given up without your help.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer turns out to be helpful, just mark it as accepted (tick the V sign).

Comment: Yup, I will, I'm new on Superuser but I come from Stackoverflow, I know how it works ^^ will keep you posted

Comment: I have no idea what Super Grub2 Disk did but it seems to be working now!!!! I booted using Super Grub2 Disk, it said Lubuntu had some updates to do, and now I rebooted the computer normally without Super Grub2 Disk and Grub bootloader is now working! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Just a little of this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70o_F6Yo7ck or perhaps a little of this https://pimpjuicetraction.com/ or a little of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimp_Juice_(drink)